# Emulator is not detected automatically unable to connect to device

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I have a Dell device and suddenly I cannot connect the Android studio to the emulator. I get the following error message:

> unable to open connection to: localhost/127.0.0.1:5037, due to:
>   java.net.connectexception: connection refused: connect

Any Idea how to fix it ?

Comment: It might be because I think you didn't accept the USB debugging accept request when you first run the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try Manually Starting the Server.

Location to your ADB.exe Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server

Comment: This is not bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after some unknown operations with my Windows 10. I tried many different ways, and finally solved it with the following steps:

1. open Command Prompt with Adminstrator privilege. (If you don't know how to, please google.)
2. "netstat -ao" to find which process takes the port of 127.0.0.1:5037. FOr example, something like

> ```
>  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         mypcname:0       LISTENING       15752
> ```

Here the culprit PID is 15752.

3. "taskkill /PID /F PID" to kill the process. Replace PID with your number, e.g., 15752.
4. retry adb. If it works, you may sometimes have to proceed with the following steps.
5. If it is a Windows service that is using the port, it may start automatically, and blocks adb subsequently. You could specify another adb server port for environment variable ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT.
6. If the Windows service is LogsAndAlerts (which is the common case for many), you can disable or delete it with:

> ```
> sc config "LogsAndAlerts" start= disabled 
>
> sc delete "LogsAndAlerts"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip) and extract it to in my case

```
C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools.
```

It worked for me.